# How to leave the selection in the Comment box after adding a comment

Tags: vba, ms-word

I know how to add a comment using VBA, but when I use my code `selection.Range.comments.Add Range:=selection.Range, Text:=""` to create a comment, then the selected range is in the main text body.

However, If I use the end-user "Add new comment" menu command built into MS Word, after creating the comment the selection is in comment part, so that I can start typing.

How can I do the same with my code: after creating a comment, the selection is in comment part / "box"?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following demonstrates how you can leave the insertion point (cursor) in the Comment "box" after inserting a comment. Just use the `Edit` method of the `Comment` object.

```
Sub SelectionInCommentBox()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim cmt As Word.Comment

    Set rng = Selection.Range
    Set cmt = rng.Comments.Add(rng, "")
    cmt.Edit       
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome, @kerry. Don't worry, if you continue to ask such well-stated questions you'll soon have enough points to upvote any contributions you find helpful on the site :-)